# getting at rechart's hover/tooltip data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get at the innards of the data object generated by recharts and used to populate their tooltips (so I can display it elsewhere). The image below shows the output of

```
console.log(data.payload[0]);
```

gained via a function placed on the Tooltip's content:

```
<Tooltip content={ this.showTooltipData.bind(this) } />
```

However, any attempt to get at the object components (Object.keys() returns the expected keys) fails with "undefined" or "null" references (edited for **LiverpoolCoder**):

```
showTooltipData = (data) => {
  console.log(data.payload[0]);
  console.log(data.payload[0].color);
}

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
    at PlotCharts._this.showTooltipData (PlotCharts.js) (...)
```

Am I missing something here?

[image: console.log(data.payload[0]);]

It still looks like a simple array. Given:

```
showTooltipData = (data) => {
  if ( typeof data.payload[0] !== 'undefined') {
    // console.log(data.payload[0].then(function(payload){ payload.color }));
    console.log(Object.keys(data.payload[0]));
    console.log("dataKey = " + data.payload[0]["datakey"]);
  }
}
```

I see, in the log (you can see in the output above that dataKey does contain a value):

[image]

EDIT: the code above works fine, "datakey" is a typo - moved to dataKey and it seems to work. For anyone else who got here via web search for the same issue - you HAVE to check (typeof as above) the existence of the data before accessing it - moving the mouse around creates and destroys the data constantly.

Comment: Are you sure swopping the console log to data.payload[0].color at the same line of code where it was data.payload[0]?

Comment: Yes. Edited above. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You seem to be using a promise. Try outputting console.log(data.payload[0].then(function(payload){ payload.color }));

Comment: Will do on Monday morning and edit - thanks!

Comment: "then is not a function" - I believe the promise reference in the error message provided above is simply due to the fact that the full data set is being returned via a promise? It looks like a simple array - added more data above.

Comment: Are you sure the Object you are displaying is data.payload[0] and not just data. If that is the case then data.color should work?

Comment: See my answer below and the edits in the OP. The data is being created and destroyed with every mouse move so its existence needs to be checked. Thanks for following and helping out though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is from above:

```
showTooltipData = (data) => {
  if ( typeof data.payload[0] !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(Object.keys(data.payload[0]));
    console.log("dataKey = " + data.payload[0]["dataKey"]);
  }
}
```

You HAVE to check (typeof as above is one way) the existence of the data before accessing it - moving the mouse around creates and destroys the data constantly.

Comment: shouldn't this just be `if (data.payload[0])`? would be much more simple